# MySQL Total Sum Update

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update, sum

```
SELECT id,100.0/(SELECT SUM(points) FROM data)*points AS reward,points FROM data;
```

The first problem I have is that I don't think this is efficient to run the inner select so many times, what is the best join to use.

The second problem is I am using the resulting dataset to generate hundreds of individual update queries, how can I update from this from the select in one query?

i.e

```
UPDATE aggregate AS a SET a.reward=a.reward+data.reward
SELECT ...
WHERE a.dataid = data.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is to move the query to the `from` clause.

The answer to your second is to do a `join` query in the `update`:

```
UPDATE aggregate a join
   (SELECT id, 100.0/sump*points AS reward, points
    FROM data cross join
         (SELECT SUM(points) as sump
          FROM data
         ) const
   ) ds
   on a.dataid = ds.id
SET a.reward = a.reward + ds.reward;
```